# The problem is importing the pytz package into Python

Tags: python, pip

Can you please tell me how I can use the `pytz` package in `Python2` version?
I am trying to run one script that works under Python2 version:

```
┌──(rootkali)-[~/passer]
└─# python passer.py                                                                              1 ⨯
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "passer.py", line 33, in <module>
    import pytz
ImportError: No module named pytz
```

I have verified that I have the package installed:

```
┌──(rootkali)-[~]
└─# pip list | grep pytz
pytz                         2020.5                                                                                                      
┌──(rootkali)-[~]
└─# pip3 list | grep pytz
pytz                         2020.5
```

Can you please tell me what could be the problem?
Thank you so much.

OS Kali linux 2020.2

Comment: `python --version` ? `pip --version` ? `pip3 --version` ?

Comment: `# pip --version`        
`pip 20.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.9)`                                                                                                                                 

`# pip3 --version`
`pip 20.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.9)`                                                                                                                             

`python --version`
`Python 2.7.18`
It is very strange why everything that I ask for Python2 still refers to the version of Python3.

Comment: Your `pip` is for wrong Python, not Python 2. Use `python -m pip`. Try `python -m pip list | grep pytz`,  `python -m pip install -U pytz`

Comment: `python -m pip`                                                                                                                    
`/usr/bin/python: No module named pip`

`python -m pip list | grep pytz` 
`/usr/bin/python: No module named pip`

`python -m pip install -U pytz`                                                                                              
`/usr/bin/python: No module named pip`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to solve this problem as follows, by requesting versions of `pip` and `pip3` packages, I noticed that all links go to `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/`
I looked at the `dist-packages` folder and saw that there are many packages, and the folder of the same name, but only in the `python` version 2 folder, is empty, i.e. here: `python2.7/dist-packages/`
I took and copied the packages I needed from the `Python3` folder to the `Python2` folder, this is of course complete absurdity, but it worked for me.
I understand that this is a temporary and not a good solution to the problem, but how can I install the necessary packages in `python2` in the future? because now everything is referring to `python3`

Comment: Your best future plan for Python 2 is to move away from it. It is a year beyond end-of-life and you can't expect ongoing support for it.

Comment: can i mark my answer as a solution? if there are no more ideas ...

Comment: Go ahead. It's a solution, just not the long-lasting one you were hoping for. The number of people who can help you with Python 2 is diminishing as everyday familiarity fades and memory becomes more uncertain. Stick with Python 2 and before long you may find yourself helping others in the same fix.